# vuetify combobox getting search string value as input on blur

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i have a simple v-combobox where i can select/deselect multiple items from a list of object.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-layout column>
      <v-form v-model="valid">
        <v-combobox
          v-model="selectedItems"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="id"
          :items="itemsList"
          label="Items"
          multiple
          clerable
          persistent-hint
          chips>
          </v-combobox>
        <div>{{selectedItems}}</div>
        </v-form>
     </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYjZaN
The problem is when i write a search string in the field and then click outside i get a chip with it instead of just doing nothing.
It looks like it depend on v-form, removing it everything will work fine.
Anyone know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are using `v-combobox`. From [their website](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox#combobox): "With Combobox, you can allow a user to create new values that may not be present in a provided items list." Try `v-autocomplete` and now if you try search a string that does not exist in your items list, you will get "data not available"

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the blur event yourself. That will remove the default v-chip creation behavior. To do this you would do `<v-combobox @blur="blurHandler()"` and add something like `blurHandler() { // Do something or nothing here }` to the script.